# What is the practical way to support multiple browser types?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser

What is the practical way to support multiple browser types?
using custom CSS per type ?
using GWT ?
some other way?

i am currently using jquery for the jscript side, and it's great, but the CSS side is starting to kill me :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455913/cross-browser-css

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that supporting "all" browsers while aiming best possible design. You should define your minimums e.g. support IE 7+, Firefox 4+ etc. Then look for each browsers that should be supported for CSS support. Say you find lowest supported version is CSS 2 in our example. Then look at CSS 2 specification which CSS rules are supported. Design your site with those CSS rules. Sometimes you can use higher CSS versions to improve your site design for up-to-date users i.e. the users who uses latest version of the browsers. Border radius, box shadows, text shadows are great example what I meant here.

There are some libraries on the internet that enable to mimic some behaviors across browsers (most of them designed especially for IE). They are mostly rely on Javascript, but there are some other methods too. If you want to play with your own way, you can rely on jQuery which is good for such usages.

These are not universal methods to support multiple browsers. But, this methods work for us.

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS part, use normalize: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/

For a great starting point that includes normalize and some invaluable tips: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of http://www.modernizr.com/ should give you a lot of help.